# iOS Swift update UICollectionView dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Well, I have a very annoying problem of updating CollectionView's dynamically. I always get the error: "UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index que path does not exist"

I made a basic design that shows fruits, added a button to show only apple, when I click this button, grab the content just have apple and send update CollectionView and I see this error ...

Here the method who updates dynamically my CollectionView:

```
@IBAction func showOnlyApple(sender: AnyObject) {
    var justApple = [FruitsObject]()
    for item in self.fruitsCollection{
        if (item.name! == "Maça") {
            justApple.append(item)
        }
    }
    self.fruits = justApple
    self.uiCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If someone wants to see the error, here's the project:
https://github.com/bkawakami/CollectionViewFruits

Just build the project and click the button, "Só Maçã"

Someone has passed or know how to solve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CardsLayout` class you are looping through a `cache` variable that is never updated in order to set the layout attributes. You're seeing this error because you are returning layout attributes for a cell that no longer exists in your datasource, but still exists in your `cache`. One way to fix this is to change your `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect)` to the following:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // Clear the cache
    cache.removeAll()

    // Call prepare layout to repopulate the cache based on the new number of items
    prepareLayout()

    for attributes in cache {
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect ) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributes
}
```

However, this defeats the purpose of your `cache` in the first place - now that you understand the issue you should be able to redesign your `CardsLayout` class accordingly.